# Not all nested array values are showing up MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a MERN app using mongoose, react etc... I am trying to use axios to create a post function to add a new list to my database. Everything works fine right up to the end. My front end passes the info to the backend using axios and routing and right before I do list.save() I even console.log what I am saving and everything looks fine. Then I will look in my database and my items in my list are only being store by their id, I can't access their name property at all. I have no clue why it's just not showing up. I'll try to give my code but everything is split into different files and folders for backend frontend so I hope my code and explanation makes sense.

```
function addList(listTitle) {
    const newList = {
    title: listTitle
    }
    
    Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/todos/add", newList)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));
}
```

Above is my post request to add the list

```
Routes.route("/add")
.post(function(req, res) {
    let list = new List({
        title: req.body.title,
        items: defaultItems
    });
    console.log(list.items)
    list.save()
        .then(list => {
            res.status(200).json({"list": "list added successfully"})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(err);
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

This is my route that works perfectly, I am able to log everything and it looks fine.

```
[{"_id":"5fdcba16b08f7b1380853557","name":"Welcome to your todolist!"},{"_id":"5fdcba16b08f7b1380853558","name":"Hit the + button to add a new item."},{"_id":"5fdcba16b08f7b1380853559","name":"<-- Hit this to delete an item."}]
```

And this is what is logged from the above console.log in the routing function, which proves the items have a name and everything. But then using my site or using postman, or just looking in my mongodb atlas collections, this is what shows up for my list items.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fdcbda6068da20c90ffc267"},"items":[{"$oid":"5fdcbd98068da20c90ffc264"},{"$oid":"5fdcbd98068da20c90ffc265"},{"$oid":"5fdcbd98068da20c90ffc266"}],"title":"anotha one","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

I have no clue why right before I do list.save() it shows my items and their names fine, but then as soon as I look in my database it's gone. I don't know if this will help or not but the items that I am saving every time are the same default items, is it possible mongoose/mongodb is just trying to reference them every time since it knows they are the same? I don't know if that helps or just confused the situation more, but please help if possible.

As requested here are my two schemas.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const itemsSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    listId: String
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', itemsSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Item = require('./Item');


var listsSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    items: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}]
  });
module.exports = mongoose.model('List', listsSchema);
```

Comment: Can you post the Schema for `List`? This looks like it may be missing "name" as a field on the schema, and mongoose will only save fields you have in your schema by default. Can't say for sure without seeing it.

Comment: Just added it to the post!

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the first console log, somehow a new property called "name" is added to the data, I am not sure where.

However your schema uses the property "title", these need to match.

I've seen mongoose exclude fields like this whenever a property is missing in my mongoose response. It is usually a conflict between the data in my query and my model.

Comment: My list schema uses the property "title", but the console.log statement is tapping into the nested item objects, which schema uses the property "name".

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***populate()*** function in mongoose to populate the ***items*** array in the List collection. Modify the post request as shown below.

```js
Routes.route("/add")
.post(function(req, res) {
    let list = new List({
        title: req.body.title,
        items: defaultItems
    });
    console.log(list.items)
    list.save()
        .then(async (list) => {
            const populatedList = await List.populate(list, [{
              path: 'items'
            }]);
            
            console.log(populatedList);
            res.status(200).json({"list": "list added successfully"})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(err);
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Comment: I changed my code to this and it didn't change anything.